# How do I extract the hotel names from this object in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm getting data in this format, and need to extract the hotel names from it. I have no idea how to do this.

```
[ 
  #<Hotel:0x007fba499de940 @data=#<CSV::Row "Hotel":"Dropp Inn" "City":"Cityville" >>,   
  #<Hotel:0x007fba499d7cf8 @data=#<CSV::Row "Hotel":"Bamboo Lodge" "City":"Cityton">>
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as

```
# Assuming in your Hotel class, you have a reader method called `data`.
array.map { |hotel| hotel.data['Hotel'] }
```

This will work, as you have *array of `Hotel` objects*, I can see from your question. Now, each `Hotel` instance is having an instance variable `@data`, which is nothing but a [`CSV::Row`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) object. Now each `CSV::Row` object has fields `"Hotel"`, `"City"`. Now to get those fields values, you need to use [`CSV::Row#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.